# Layout for a custom component leads to a 404 Error

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, layout

I need to create a new page for my custom component, however I don't want (and I don't need) to create a new view for that.
I know that this can be achieved by creating layouts; the problem is that my layouts lead me to a 404 error.

I created a layout called `thumbnails.php`

My path: `com_gallery/views/tmpl/thumbnails.php`

I access it by this URL: `[root]index.php?option=com_gallery&view=gallery&layout=thumbnails`

It seems that all is set correctly, but still I get a 404 error.

Do I have to register the layout or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally view layouts should be placed in view layout directory. In your case it's `components/com_gallery/views/gallery/tmpl`

Comment: I actually had this setup before asking the question, I just forgot to add "gallery" to the path on my post; however it wasn't working but now it does. I don't know what's changed. Maybe something was cached or I don't know.